# redmi 2 prime not charging and phone not going to turn on

Tags: wi-fi

Its battery drained to 0% and I plugged the phone for 1 hour but its still not turned on.How much time its takes to charge 0 to 1% and I cant find also that the phone is charging or not because it is not showing any logo or battery sign.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to my phone 
I just removed the battery for about 2 min and then connect the phone with pc through usb cable and after few minutes it starts showing charging icon